# Ubuntu MATE 15.04 very long boot

Tags: boot

I just installed ubuntu mate 15.04 on my hp notebook and it takes very long time to boot (like 5 minutes). After that everything runs great. How can I check what is the problem that causes this? I used `dmesg` command and got [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/matek2305/3d589a6b477ffc014626/raw/c91936323947fb93189f41b238a9c2c70d75481e/boot). I can see that thera are several lags there but it is not clear to me how can I deal with them. Maybe someone is familiar with this problem and can help me me? I would be thankful.

Result of `systemd-analyze blame command`:

```
   3min 42ms systemd-udev-settle.service
      8.846s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      6.496s mysql.service
      5.949s gpu-manager.service
      5.687s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.577s ModemManager.service
      4.252s dev-disk-by\x2duuid-51885ac5\x2daf27\x2d4d13\x2db5bd\x2d9eb591337c94.device
      4.069s NetworkManager.service
      3.977s udisks2.service
      3.490s accounts-daemon.service
      3.232s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      2.368s bluetooth.service
      2.352s systemd-logind.service
      2.348s rsyslog.service
      2.348s irqbalance.service
      2.347s grub-common.service
      2.346s loadcpufreq.service
      2.344s avahi-daemon.service
      2.344s apport.service
      2.342s pppd-dns.service
      2.341s console-kit-log-system-start.service
      2.074s apparmor.service
      1.862s console-kit-daemon.service
      1.532s systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service
       992ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       933ms polkitd.service
       892ms lightdm.service
       653ms systemd-journald.service
       613ms systemd-modules-load.service
       598ms virtualbox.service
       520ms systemd-udevd.service
       515ms resolvconf.service
       405ms upower.service
       393ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       389ms dbus.service
       388ms ufw.service
       346ms ondemand.service
       342ms systemd-sysctl.service
       337ms console-setup.service
       335ms networking.service
       319ms ifup-wait-all-auto.service
       281ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       274ms kerneloops.service
       260ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       259ms dev-mqueue.mount
       259ms systemd-setup-dgram-qlen.service
       259ms dev-hugepages.mount
       222ms rtkit-daemon.service
       187ms plymouth-read-write.service
       184ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       178ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill0.service
       177ms systemd-random-seed.service
       170ms systemd-fsck-root.service
       164ms systemd-vconsole-setup.service
       145ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        87ms rc-local.service
        86ms user@1000.service
        86ms dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap
        47ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        47ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        31ms alsa-restore.service
        29ms dns-clean.service
        28ms udev-finish.service
        22ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        20ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        17ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
        15ms speech-dispatcher.service
        13ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2efe9f37\x2d4717\x2d4dcb\x2da28f\x2d9d9a05cfa657.service
        12ms plymouth-start.service
         7ms ntp.service
         3ms media-data.mount
         3ms cpufrequtils.service
         2ms ureadahead-stop.service
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill3.service
```

After `systemctl mask systemd-udev-settle`:

```
     11.658s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
     10.468s apparmor.service
      5.950s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      5.927s dev-disk-by\x2duuid-51885ac5\x2daf27\x2d4d13\x2db5bd\x2d9eb591337c94.device
      5.549s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.458s dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap
      4.057s mysql.service
      3.766s gpu-manager.service
      3.083s systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service
      2.572s ModemManager.service
      2.519s NetworkManager.service
      2.341s systemd-udevd.service
      2.066s accounts-daemon.service
      1.873s console-setup.service
      1.638s systemd-logind.service
      1.631s grub-common.service
      1.631s rsyslog.service
      1.627s avahi-daemon.service
      1.442s systemd-fsck-root.service
      1.303s bluetooth.service
      1.303s loadcpufreq.service
      1.301s pppd-dns.service
      1.196s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       696ms systemd-modules-load.service
       656ms ifup-wait-all-auto.service
       599ms resolvconf.service
       552ms console-kit-daemon.service
       505ms systemd-setup-dgram-qlen.service
       504ms dev-hugepages.mount
       432ms apport.service
       428ms polkitd.service
       422ms console-kit-log-system-start.service
       395ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       351ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill1.service
       342ms alsa-restore.service
       332ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       332ms irqbalance.service
       330ms ufw.service
       329ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       329ms systemd-vconsole-setup.service
       267ms udisks2.service
       264ms systemd-journald.service
       257ms systemd-sysctl.service
       222ms virtualbox.service
       190ms lightdm.service
       189ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       174ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       174ms dev-mqueue.mount
       160ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill0.service
       160ms networking.service
       152ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       145ms systemd-random-seed.service
       144ms dbus.service
       109ms kerneloops.service
        63ms dns-clean.service
        44ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        39ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        38ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        30ms user@1000.service
        13ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
        12ms plymouth-start.service
        11ms plymouth-read-write.service
        11ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2efe9f37\x2d4717\x2d4dcb\x2da28f\x2d9d9a05cfa657.service
         6ms ntp.service
         5ms speech-dispatcher.service
         4ms upower.service
         3ms cpufrequtils.service
         3ms ondemand.service
         3ms media-data.mount
         2ms ureadahead-stop.service
         2ms rtkit-daemon.service
         1ms udev-finish.service
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms rc-local.service
```

Comment: use `systemd-analyze blame` to see what is taking so long

Comment: or, systemd can make a cool svg chart of the boot process by running the following command `systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg` the svg image will be created in the current (most likely ~/) directory. It loads best if you view the file in a browser like firefox for some reason.

Comment: added result of the command to first post

Comment: Ok we are getting somewhere... add the output of `systemctl status systemd-udev-settle` ;)

Comment: See if `systemctl mask systemd-udev-settle` works. Found it here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1475652#p1475652

Comment: Ok I did systemctl mask systemd-udev-settle and it is a lot faster now. Thanks a lot! There are still some thing that takes more than 10secs now but i dont know if it is bug or normal behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ...

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

and check if there is a service that takes a long time to start.

Regarding this service I found this on the web. 3 people claim masking it works in getting the startup time down to mere seconds:

```
sudo systemctl mask systemd-udev-settle
```

Comment: Where exactly should I append this line to enable bootcharting?

Comment: Like so: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time

Comment: `systemd-analyze blame` is enabled by default

Comment: @mchid make it an answer and Ill remove this one ;)

Comment: I added result of systemd-analyze command and there is service that is taking more than 3 minutes when booting so it looks like source of the problem, but still dont know how to deal with it.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks anyhow, we all benefit in the end